# How to make a choice field depending on model choices

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model as follows:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    residential = 'residential'
    commercial = 'commercial'
    outright = 'outright'
    lease = 'lease'
    empty = ''
    types = ((residential, 'residential'), (commercial, 'commercial'), (outright, 'outright'), (lease, 'lease'), (empty, ''))
    property_type = models.CharField(choices=types, default=empty, max_length=20)
```

I now have a ModelForm as follows:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-area', 'placeholder': 'Enter name for Property'}), required=True)
    desc = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-area', 'placeholder': 'Enter a small description', 'rows': '5', 'style': 'resize:none;'}), required=True)
    property_type = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.Select(types)) #This is where I want to add the choices available in the Property Model.
```

I tried this method

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-area', 'placeholder': 'Enter name for Property'}), required=True)
    desc = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-area', 'placeholder': 'Enter a small description', 'rows': '5', 'style': 'resize:none;'}), required=True)
    residential = 'residential'
    commercial = 'commercial'
    outright = 'outright'
    lease = 'lease'
    empty = ''
    types = ((residential, 'residential'), (commercial, 'commercial'), (outright, 'outright'), (lease, 'lease'), (empty, ''))
    property_type = models.CharField(choices=types, default=empty, max_length=20)
```

However, this gave me `'tuple' object has no attribute 'copy'` error. Going through Django Docs, I saw a solution [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#a-full-example) but I'm not sure how this works. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In the form, the field `property_type` must be must be `ChoiceField` not `CharField` Look:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-area', 'placeholder': 'Enter name for Property'}), required=True)
    desc = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control input-area', 'placeholder': 'Enter a small description', 'rows': '5', 'style': 'resize:none;'}), required=True)
    residential = 'residential'
    commercial = 'commercial'
    outright = 'outright'
    lease = 'lease'
    empty = ''
    types = ((residential, 'residential'), (commercial, 'commercial'), (outright, 'outright'), (lease, 'lease'), (empty, ''))
    property_type = models.ChoiceField(choices=types, default=empty, max_length=20)
```